# RemoveAttr that doesn't remove id?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/hsKba/1/)

What's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.navi-ring').hover(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr("id"); // this doesnt work!
        )};
)};
```

It doesnt remove id! It should change color then but it doesnt.

```
.navi-ring:nth-child(1):hover{
background-color:yellow;
```

it should remoev ID (with border image) but it doesnt. then the circle should turn yellow.

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code and you haven't loaded jQuery in your demo http://jsfiddle.net/hsKba/7/, generally removing IDs is not a good idea.

Comment: Do not just copy/paste code. Write it by yourself. If you do that you will notice that brackets are like this `(function(){})`

Comment: oh I see why its bad now... I wanted to hide ID only when mouseenter and return this when mouseleave. is there any other option to do this?

Comment: Try using the JSHint feature for jsFiddle. It immediately found your syntax errors.

Comment: there could be other (probably pure CSS) ways of achieving same result given there are no constraints enforce you to use it.

Comment: There are pure CSS ways, but maybe OP is learning jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`)}` should be `})` in both instances of it appearing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.navi-ring').hover(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("id");
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/hsKba/9/)

You haven't included jQuery in your fiddle and you had syntex error in your code. You were not ending your braces properly.